# Can the size of range proofs be reduced?

Tags: ringct, range-proofs

Range proofs are currently quite large, roughly 12-30kb. Is it  likely that range proofs will become smaller in the future through various optimizations?

Answer (score 9):

They are currently 6304 bytes (per output).

This will drop in the future by at least 1024 bytes. Beyond that will change (or not) with design decisions yet to be made.