# What changes are planned for the September 2017 hard fork?

Tags: ringsize, hard-fork

I am having trouble finding information about which of the following will be included in the September 2017 hard fork:

1. Fluffy blocks
2. Minimum / uniform ringsize
3. ZMQ (Zero MQ)
4. ?

Is there a reliable resource where I can view which major changes/features are slated to be included in the next hard fork? The closest thing I could find is https://getmonero.org/resources/roadmap/ which is vague and does not seem to be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only change from that list which actually requires a HF is the minimum / uniform ringsize. The other 2 can be rolled out at any time. AFAIK, the current list for the upcoming hard fork is:

1. Only RCT transactions will be allowed
2. Minimum / uniform ringsize
3. Range proof [size reduction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/how-will-the-range-proof-size-reduction-be-accomplished)

and the exact date hasn't been decided yet.

The discussion on 2. can be found [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1673).

For 3., I've not yet seen any code or Github issue so hard to tell the progress of this. Luigi1111 (one of "core team") is working on it.

The best way to be on top of things is to monitor the [dev meetings](https://getmonero.org/blog/tags/dev%20diaries.html) which get published on a few places, or just stalk various [community channels](https://getmonero.org/community/hangouts/). There's not something like a "live HF list", but anyone could volounteer to keep track. All it takes is to have a chat with some key contributors, make a list and add a page to the [official site repo](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site).

In any case, a [version tag will be made on Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases) prior to HF, and that will happen some ample time before the HF date where everyone will be able to easily see what gets changed.

Answer (score 2):

Neither fluffyblocks nor ZMQ/0MQ require any network consensus, so those don't need to be thought of as being included "in" the hard fork.

To my knowledge, a minimum ringsize will be one major protocol rule enforced at the next hard fork.  Additionally, another protocol rule change will be the rejection of non-RingCT transactions.  Both of those network rules require a hard fork.

To my knowledge, it hasn't been settled yet whether a fixed ringsize will be enforced due to network rules.  If there is a change, it will likely be a wallet change only (not a protocol rule).  If it's a protocol rule, it is very unlikely to be settled in time for this hard fork.